# stripe.checkout.Session.create not being triggered Python

Tags: python, flask, stripe-payments

This is my first time using Stripe in `Python`, and I'm having a bit of trouble.

Here is the flow of my code:

```
@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    async def signup():
        if 'email' in session:
            return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
        else:
            if request.method == 'POST':
                data = request.get_json()
                await insertSignUp(request)
                await payments(request)
                return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
            if request.method == 'GET':
                if request.args.get('plan'):
                    plan = request.args.get('plan')
                    return render_template('sign-up.html', plan=plan)
                else:
                    return render_template('sign-up.html', plan=None)
```

and then in `insertSignUp`, I am returning `return jsonify("Success")`, which if I do: `isInserted = await insertSignUp(request)`, and print isInserted, it shows successfully.

I believe where the problem lies is in `payments`. Please see the function below:

```
async def payments(request):
data = request.get_json()

plan = data.get('submitObj', {}).get('plan')
email = data.get('submitObj', {}).get('email')

price_id = ''
if plan == 'Bronze':
    price_id = 'bronze_test'
elif plan == 'Silver':
    price_id = 'silver_test'
elif plan == 'Gold':
    price_id = 'gold_test'
    
session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
    success_url='http://127.0.0.1:5000/subscribe/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
    cancel_url='http://127.0.0.1:5000/subscribe/cancel',
    mode='subscription',
    line_items=[{
        'price': price_id,
        'quantity': 1
    }],
    customer_email=email
)


@app.route('/subscribe/success', methods=['GET'])
def subscribe_success():
    print("do we ever come in here?")
    if request.method == 'GET':
        session_id = request.args.get('session_id')
        session = stripe.checkout.Session.retrieve(session_id)
        customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve(session.customer)
        email = customer.email
        collection = db['chatbotAuth']
        collection.update_one({ 'email': email }, { '$set': { 'subscribed': True  } })
        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
    return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
```

However, once I get into the `payments` route, nothing happens! it just hangs. So I put some print statements in there, and it is logging the correct data, however, it is my assumption that `stripe.checkout.Session.create` is never getting triggered. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't have any logs inside `payments`. Is the Stripe function being called? What is being returned if so? Your code is supposed to store the response of that call in a variable and then redirect to the `url` property on that object. See https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart

Comment: try a `print(session)` after the session call. My bet is on your Price ID not actually being a Price ID ('gold_test' is not a Price ID, unless your account is capable of setting custom Price IDs)

Comment: On another note - at what point is your Customer redirected to the Session you created ? So they can complete it ? From what I'm seeing, you create the Session, then on the `success_url` you check the Session, then add them to your db, but at no point you seem to redirect them to the Session, so they can eventually get to that `success_url`. Maybe what you're missing is the `return redirect(session.url)`